# How to test that a warning was generated

Tags: unit-test

In one of the classes I need to support, there is a need to fetch additional data for a record. There is a function allowing the pre-fetching of data for multiple records to support bulkified triggers, but if the data is not prefetched (cached) then a single query must be performed.

When a single query is performed, I'm generating a warning using System.debug. In my Unit Test, I'd like to test that this warning is being generated. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It is not possible to check that a debug occurs. You could alternatively create a `@TestVisible Boolean` that you check instead.

Comment: or write warnings to an sobject called Log__c (or something like that) and then test presence of a record in Log__c with your warning.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson, I think that approach may be my best bet.